# How do I solve this water reflection puzzle in the Desert Ruins?

Tags: the-witness

I'm stuck here in the last puzzle in flooded basement of desert ruin. As you can observe below [see image], I can only see part of the solution. Is it possible to find the remaining part from a different angle or do I need to guess the remaining part?

[image: Desert ruin flooded basement]

I am not asking for the solution - I just want to know if I am missing something here or if we are only supposed to see part of the solution in the water reflection no matter which angle we see it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, you have to make the water level rise and lower in order to see the entire solution.

Basically, you will only be able to see part of the solution at any given time. I suggest writing down what you see so that you don't forget. That way, once you have the full picture drawn, you can just put in the correct solution.

A tip from [this site](http://www.gosunoob.com/witness/desert-ruin-puzzle-solutions/) says the following:

> This might be the hardest panel to solve because parts of the solution are obfuscated. Best angle is from across where the puzzle panel is.

If you want the solution, I've put it below:

> [image]

Comment: i tried that but i only see the same part of solution no matter the water rising level.

Comment: @KalyanamKiran it has been quite a while since I played, but I recall having to move around the room while the water level is changing to see the different parts of the solution. It took quite a few tries to see the whole picture.

Comment: so u did see the whole solution? u didn't guess the remaining part?

Comment: @KalyanamKiran I remember being able to see the whole solution, though not all at once, yes.

Comment: I also remember having to move around to see different parts of the solution _(and that it was a bitch to solve)_.  IIRC there's also a light you have to turn on/off to see different parts of the solution.

Comment: @Vemonus thanx, i've looked around for a while and found the remaining part. i was looking at it all along and thought it's the shadow of one of those supporting sticks below the walking paths.

Comment: @KalyanamKiran so you were able to solve it? Awesome!

Comment: Stand just to the left of the panel, very close to it and look down in the water to see the scratches on the left part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Can'tCode can you describe what angle you have to look from in order to see the right side of the puzzle? I found the two viewpoints in Denilson Sá Maia's answer below, but can't figure out how to see the rightmost part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I found two places where we can see the reflection:

[image: Across from the panel, when the water is low]

[image: To the left of the panel, when the water is high]

They are really difficult to see, because you have to be in the right spot, and the reflection is so far away it is tiny on the screen. Reducing the FOV (Esc -> Settings -> Field of View) for this puzzle may help, but just remember to restore the FOV to a value comfortable for your eyes.

After spending about one hour on this single panel, I gave up.

Comment: I got stuck here too. So frustrating. This is probably the place where I started looking for online guides to help solve the puzzles, because it was just too much.